# Including Less Boundary Detail in Zoomed out Map of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, display

I have a large map in ArcGis with a great deal of boundary detail which I don't need.

My issue is when my map is zoomed out the outline of these extremely detailed boundaries block other important features on my map.

What is the best way to either remove this extra detail or make it so the boundaries aren't drawn with such detail?

Answer (score 2):

you can copy layers . for example copy slope layer.one layer with Hollow symbology(slope with boundary)  and use outline color 0 value for another layer ( slope without boundary) . then go to the properties of layer with hollow symbology(boundary layer) ->tab general->scale range , and select don't show layer when zoomed . use scale of interset .
[image: see slope example] :